# how to convert c program to cgi?

Tags: c, linux, cgi

I try to run a simple cgi progrem that print hello world.
 
HTML:

```
< a href="url/cgi-bin/hello.cgi">click< /a>
```

c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");  
    printf("<html>");
    printf("<head>");
    printf("<title>Test</title>");
    printf("</head>");
    printf("<body>");
    printf("<p>Hello world!</p>");
    printf("</body>");
    printf("</html>\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I create the cgi file in the terminal: gcc hello.c -o hello.cgi

But when I put the file in the server, I get 404 error.

Comment: Can you post the server log to see the full error? Do you have enabled cgi-bin?

Comment: assuming the url is correct and configured in the web server, have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: Your program is working correctly in my machine. So check your server configuration or the url.

Comment: http://www.websiteamit.bugs3.com/ttt.html , I think that the server isnt support this type of file. This is my first time that I use cgi file so probably this is some stupid mistake. thank you

Comment: main return int, not void.  You need to end the final printf with a newline.

Comment: I changed to int and add \n but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you configure the server to serve CGI from where you put the executable? Or alternatively, did you put the executable somewhere the server expects to serve CGI from?

Comment: I think that this is the problem but I don't know where to put the CGI file

Comment: someone know server that support cgi file? that will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a 404 error because you're using a relative path (even though you're trying to use an absolute path) in your HTML.

Your HTML code is as follows (based on the link in the comments):

```
<a href="www.websiteamit.bugs3.com/cgi-bin/hello.cgi">click</a>
```

When you click it, the browser thinks you want to go to `http://www.websiteamit.bugs3.com/www.websiteamit.bugs3.com/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`. Which of course does not exist, and so you get a 404. If you add `http://` in front of your `www`, it will go to the correct path on the server.

However, your server is not configured correctly to run the CGI program - instead it serves the file as a download. Your website's configuration is seriously broken. You need to tell the webserver to run the program as CGI rather than download it - by creating a `.htaccess` file, I would guess, but it's difficult to troubleshoot. Check [this page](http://www.htaccess-guide.com/enable-cgi-outside-of-the-cgi-bin/) on how to write one that executes CGI for all files with `.cgi` extension. The script also needs to have execute permissions set - try using the Web SSH console that the hosting package provides to set those on the script.